# Let's update the tour- what should be added?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, help-center

Last year we [updated the modal for new users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10483/120114). There are many comments left on posts, especially new posts, asking OPs to "[take the tour](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour)" (especially when a post is off-topic).

The tour has not had any substantial edits in seven years and while that isn't really an issue, we can update it to make it more useful for new users.

How about we add the numbered list ([suggested by Peilonrayz May 17th, 2020](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10485/120114)) plus the line above it that mentions the help center pages, which was added to the modal?

> To get you the best answers, we’ve provided some guidance:
>
> Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a
> good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)
>
> 1. Code **must** produce the desired output
> 2. Code **must** not error or contain known bugs
> 3. Titles **should** describe what the code does
> 4. The **more** code you provide the **more** we can help

It would look like this:

[image: preview of updates]

#### Update Aug. 30, 2021

The [tour](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) has been updated with the suggestions above as well as in [the answer by mickmackusa](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10702/120114) and [the comment by Toby](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10701/lets-update-the-tour-what-should-be-added#comment21163_10702).

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Should the following be added?

5. After an answer is posted, you **must not** edit your question to invalidate any advice.

This is one of the rules here that users from other communities won't be accustomed to.

I also recommend that "not" be made bold in `2.`.

Finally, I see "we've provided some guidance:"  (note the colon).

Maybe a period after "guidance" and I am expecting a pure bullet point list of sentences (ending with punctuation) instead of an un-numbered sentenced followed by four numbered sentences without ending punctuation.

Comment: If we just moved the "Please read" sentence after the list, then the colon and rest of the grammar would be fine again.

Comment: Yep. Sure.  That works well too.

Answer (score 6):

I recently asked a user if the code posted in a question was written or maintained by them, since it was not explicitly stated in the description that they wrote it or maintain it. They asked why I asked. I replied with the standard response with a link to [the help center page *What topics can I ask about here?*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  [“*For licensing, moral, and procedural reasons, we cannot review code written by other programmers. We expect you, as the author, to understand why the code is written the way that it is.*”](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

The user has been a member for more than 6 years and taken the tour (hence has earned the [informed badge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/badges/89/informed)). I would hope people who read the tour would know that the code posted needs to be written and/or maintained by them.

## Let's add another list item to the numbered list on the tour

> #### 1. Code must be written or maintained by you.

I am open to having it lower in the list but it seems like it is of high precedence so I would vote it be one of the first items, hence why it is near the top of the list of questions on the [on-topic page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

### Edit

Okay - Let us use list item position #3.

Comment: I think CNIONWAI should be #1 - unless things have change we still have 60% CNIONWAI