# Does the question "Testing current, new or friends firms as max output and least effort" lack code to be reviewable?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I came across "[Testing current, new or friends firms as max output and least effort](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/124775/42401)" the other day, and have been thinking it's off-topic.
There is too little information to do more than a 'lint review'.

The core class(es) aren't there and so forces us to stick with code that just seems wrong.
This is as most lines are calling undefined functions, where we don't know how they are implemented, which is as helpful as hypothetical code.

We don't allow stub code, hypothetical code or pseudocode on Code Review. I find the [stub code explanation](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3652/42401) best to explain why this too should be closed:

> If your question contains stub code, then there are significant pieces of the core functionality missing, and we need you to fill in the details.
>   Excerpts of large projects are fine, but if you have omitted too much, then reviewers are left imagining how your program works.

Should we close this question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The question would be a good question, if the rest is added. Now it can be reviewed, but only shallow. We lack information for anything better.

Questions with good context get good answers. Questions without get shallow answers. If he wants something better, he should add the rest.

But, it is reviewable. Not with the [performance](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance) tag though. I've removed this hoping on an edit from OP:

> I have removed the performance tag, since we can't profile it without having all the required code. Feel free to put it back when you've added the rest.