# Feedback on closing 'Separation of concerns in graph theory project'

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-close

[Separation of concerns in graph theory project](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/106295/)

This question is odd:

- It has tons of code removed, making it hard to review (it sure does not run)
- "I am having problems with separating the concerns" sounds like "My teacher told me that there is no separation of concern, but I have no clue what that means."
- It has 6 upvotes
- 200_success edited it without downvoting or voting to close

I am ->this<- close to vote to close, but would like community feedback first.

Comment: There's a link to a running version at the bottom of the question.

Comment: hmm.. it's also 11 months old.

Answer (score 3):

I think that your first bullet-point is the only valid reason to close that question.
I'll explain my reasoning for the following three bullet points are not valid reasons:

- The rule [reviewers may comment on any part of the code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), means we don't have to answer users specific concerns. And so a question shouldn't be off-topic for something we can all just ignore.
- [Sometimes we upvote questions that are off-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Ayes+score%3A1).
  This question is not definitely on or off topic,
  and so people may just err on the side of a silent upvote.

  Honestly a quick skim to me, I don't know too much JavaScript, looked fine.
  If I liked the premise of the question I'd probably upvoted it too.
- I too think this, if *the* 200_success didn't think it was bad, it can't be bad can it?
  But look at their edit. It just changes a tag, I know I edit questions tags even if it's possibly off-topic.
  Others probably do too.

  Also this, and the point above, are both ad hominems, and it'd best if we don't use these to justify *any* decisions.

---

As for your first reason, [I don't like questions stripped of context](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6702/42401).
I don't answer them, ever.

I read the code in the question line by line, and had a lot of WTFs.
Normally this can translate into a good review, like 'WTF, don't do that'.
However mine were more Where The F is this variable.
Maybe I don't know enough JavaScript, and so the variables are clearly there for those well versed in JavaScript and d3.

But if I knew a lot more JavaScript and felt the same way I'd put down a [VTC as stub code](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3652/42401).
<sup>(But I may not know how to correctly use this close reason, as outlined by my above meta post.)</sup>