# Can I ask a question about code explanation?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm experimenting with JS canvas, trying to create pan and zoom effect. I've got the [pan](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/138030/panning-js-canvas) working. I've also got the [zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38810242/set-canvas-zoom-scale-origin) working but with a little help from SO. The zoom effect seems much more complicated than pan. Even though I've got a working code, I don't fully understand how it works, but I want to!

I don't have any problem in the code. I'm not trying to improve anything. I just want to know how the code works. Am I allowed to post a question where I want my code explained?

If not, can anyone lead me to somewhere where I can post this question or read up on the subject?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My question was closed as being off-topic. What are my options?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3649/my-question-was-closed-as-being-off-topic-what-are-my-options)

Comment: " I'm not trying to improve anything" this qualifies for **off topicness**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## No.

If we look at the [close-reason meta thread, it clearly says](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3654/42401):

> We also expect you to understand how your code works. If you are seeking an explanation of how your code works, then we will treat the question as if someone else wrote it.

And that is off-topic, 100%.

Answer (score 4):

No, because you're not looking for a review. It's... as simple as that, I'm afraid. Review answers would be useless to you.