# Is it ok to ask here how code works?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have a working piece of code without any documentation and explanation, but I don't understand how it works. Can I ask such questions or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## No

From our [close reason meta thread](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3654/42401):

> We also expect you to understand how your code works. If you are seeking an explanation of how your code works, then we will treat the question as if someone else wrote it.

Comment: Well, understandable.