# "unclear what you're asking" vs "Lacks concrete context"

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Aren't these two close reasons too similar? Since the *Lacks concrete context* exists I cannot remember using the *unclear what you're asking* anymore.

- unclear what you're asking

  > Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
- Lacks concrete context

  > Code Review requires concrete code from a project, with sufficient context for reviewers to understand how that code is used.

I think they could be merged into a single close reason and the new *Lacks concrete context* could be put on the first page.

Comment: Unclear What you're asking is a network-wide close-reason. We can not just change it. Lacking concrete context is the old "pseudocode" close reason, that was expanded a little bit.

Comment: @Vogel612 oh, I see... then _lacks concrete context_ shouldn't be an off-topic reason since one cannot say whether a question is off-topic until the quesiton is clear eanough... but this is probably a discussion for another day.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Note: ["unclear what you're asking" has been changed](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/12/05/new-post-notices-improving-feedback-on-stack-overflow-questions/). This answer still holds with the new version.

> **Closed**. This question needs [details or clarity](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). It is not currently accepting answers.

---

## Scenario 1

A user posts a full program without any description and a vague title.

- This ***is*** '**unclear what you're asking**', as we don't know if the op want a review, if the code works, well really we don't know anything the op wants.
- This ***doesn't*** '**Lacks concrete context**', as we have the entire program, we can install it locally and run it. And so it's not [pseudocode, etc](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3652).

## Scenario 2

A user posts a full project description with a question on how to improve their code. But the code is pseudocode as how they'd do it.

- This ***is not*** '**unclear what you're asking**', as we know exactly what they are asking.
- This ***does*** '**Lacks concrete context**', as we don't have the code to review - it's pseudocode.

---

And so it comes down to whether it's a problem with the description or the code. These lines can blur when a question has both problems, but that's rare and you have the choice on which close reason to close as. I personally would close as '*unclear what you're asking*' in those situations.

Answer (score 10):

"*Unclear what you're asking*" is, paradoxically, unclear for Code Review, because every question is asking the same thing: "*How can I improve this code?*".

I interpret it as "**Unclear what this code is supposed to achieve**," and I use it for questions that have a code dump with no explanation of requirements, or an explanation that is so muddled or confusing that it can't be understood enough to edit into shape except by the author.

I use "*Lacks concrete context*" for code that does have a satisfactory explanation, but is

- missing critical parts of the code (such as type definitions, database schemas/indexes, or a required library that isn't mentioned), or
- obviously stub/skeleton code (comments such as `do something here...`, or variables called `myFoo`, for example).

Comment: While I agree the basic question is "How can I improve this code?" sometimes they might be seeking advice about performance. It may not be clear what they want to improve.

Comment: It does not matter, reviewers review what they want to review anyway. Asking what should be reviewed is (or should be) optional.