# How can I improve this off-topic question about downloading anonymous type data?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

My [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/192264/function-to-download-anonymous-type-data-into-excel) is flagged as off-topic:

> Lacks concrete context.

How can I improve this question?

The `//...` in the edit history is added to tell viewers that it might or might not have more properties, since it's against the rule, I removed it. But even without it, the code still works without error.

Answer (score 4):

After the edit it is no longer obvious that the code presented is shortened code. Accordingly I reopened the question.

Do note that answers may address any and all parts of a question. That also implies that they may comment on things you did not even notice.
To enable answerers to make observations about the code that you might have missed, it's important to present code as close to your production code as possible.

That also plays into additional context you can provide for your code.
For a fuller consideration of shortened code, you could check the [explanatory meta-answer for the close reason "Lacks Concrete Context"](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3649/my-question-was-closed-as-being-off-topic-what-are-my-options/3652#3652).