# I changed my question after comments

Tags: discussion

I closed an earlier post asking for **code**-feedback on the Click CLI framework I wrote for my scripts.

I reopened the question simply about my approach to templating scripts. I rewrote the post as an **outline**

[A Simple Module Framework for Python Click](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/194510/45976)

However, the same off-topic tag is applied, but no comments.

Please provide further feedback so I can try to bring the post back on-topic.

Answer (score 11):

Your question didn't have any code to be reviewed, that is why it was closed.

> ... what I'd like feedback on, is a critique of my  *general description* and  *outline of a Framework* for creating Click CLI scripts.

Unfortunately, this is not what we do here on Code Review. Instead we review code that has been written to accomplish a task, we need to see that your code accomplishes the given task.

Please take note of some of the following posts about asking questions on Code Review.

- [The question does not include the code to be reviewed](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3653)
- [Code Review's Help page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help)

  - [Code Review's Help page about specifically about asking questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/asking)

Comment: Ok. So maybe on-topic on software engineering?

Comment: @xtian make sure you give a good read to their guidance about on-topic vs off-topic; I'm not sure anyone here would advocate you putting it somewhere else without reviewing that. It will save you more possible hassle.

Comment: Duly noted. I might just find my post has no place on SE.

Comment: @xtian Head over to [The Whiteboard](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard) and ask them there. From my knowledge of Software Engineering though, your question would be too broad for their site. You are currently asking multiple different things in your question.