# What was wrong with my question?

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions, code-length, third-party

My question [eLearning webapp made with Django](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/255751/elearning-webapp-made-with-django) was recently closed for:

> Authorship of code: Since Code Review is a community where programmers improve their skills through peer review, we require that the code be [posted by an author or maintainer of the code](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3654), that the code be [embedded directly](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3653), and that the poster know why the code is written the way it is.

The code is mine, and I know why it's written the way it is. Only explanation is the "code must be embedded in the post" clause. It's a pretty big project; is it okay to just include 2 thousand lines of code in it? (assuming that doesn't exceed the character limit)

The person who closed the question provided NO feedback beyond "this is not suitable for the site". I don't know if it's policy here, but I've always received in-depth feedback on other SE sites for closures and stuff like that. They didn't even say whether there was any type of edit that could have been done to the post to make it adhere to the guidelines.

Comment: The problem is that the code to be reviewed must be **embeded directly** in the question. As it stands, there is no code in the question and nothing to review.

Comment: Thank you. I'll edit my question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like @1201ProgramAlarm mentioned in the comment

> The problem is that the code to be reviewed must be embeded directly
> in the question. As it stands, there is no code in the question and
> nothing to review.

, which is clearly stated in the close-reason with an additional link to a meta-answer providing additional context about why this is needed.

For a question without code this is sufficient without a comment. Just take the time to read through the link and you should know how to edit a question to make it on-topic.

Once the question is edited by posting the code the question will go to the review-queue and it will be reopened if the code matches the on-topic-requirements.